# Python bokeh Google Maps dynamic glyph size based on zoom

Tags: python, google-maps, bokeh

Is it possible in Python bokeh to plot a `Circle()` glyph object in a `GMapPlot` canvas with dynamic size based on zoom? I want to display a circle area where I have the center point and a radius in meters. And I want this circle to be displayed in smaller and larger sizes based on zooming the Google Map.

Can this be achieved in some way?

---

**UPDATE:**
I can plot fix sized circles with the following code:

```
from bokeh.document import Document
from bokeh.embed import file_html
from bokeh.resources import INLINE
from bokeh.models import (GMapPlot, GMapOptions, ColumnDataSource,
    Circle, DataRange1d, PanTool, WheelZoomTool, BoxSelectTool)

map_options = GMapOptions(lat=30.29, lng=-97.73, map_type="roadmap", zoom=11)

plot = GMapPlot(x_range=DataRange1d(), y_range=DataRange1d(), map_options=map_options,
    title="Austin", api_key=GOOGLE_API_KEY)

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(lat=[30.29, 30.20, 30.29],
    lon=[-97.70, -97.74, -97.78],))

circle = Circle(x="lon", y="lat", size=15, fill_color="blue", fill_alpha=0.8,
    line_color=None)

plot.add_glyph(source, circle)

plot.add_tools(PanTool(), WheelZoomTool(), BoxSelectTool())

# Save HTML file    
doc = Document()
doc.add_root(plot)

filename = './google_maps_test.html'

with open(filename, "w") as f:
    f.write(file_html(doc, INLINE, 'Google Maps plot'))
```

Here `size=15` means pixels or some fixed size that doesn't change when I'm scrolling the diagram... I could have a `radius` in my `ColumnDataSource` object where the values would be the radius in meters (eg. 50, 75, 100). And I would use `size=radius`...

Thank you!

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I updated my question with a sample code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Circle` glyph accepts (one of) both `size` and `radius` properties. By default `size` is in "screen units" (pixels, basically). This is why they stay the same size, regardless of zoom level. If you want the circles to scale with zoom level, it's better to supply a `radius` value, since by default `radius` is interpreted to be in "data space units". I.e. in this case, it would be in meters (since the units of a `GMapPlot` axis is in meters).

```
circle = Circle(x="lon", 
                y="lat", 

                # corresponds to 15 meters, so scales accordingly with zoom
                radius=15,         

                fill_color="blue", 
                fill_alpha=0.8,
                line_color=None)
```

Comment: In my real code I wanted to use `CircleX` but it has no `radius` attribute :(( `AttributeError: unexpected attribute 'radius' to CircleX` Of course `Circle` would also do my job...

Comment: Right, only `Circle` has `radius` (to support bubble charts) all other markers are "scatter" markers, and only support `size`.

Comment: I'll mention Bokeh is extensible. It's not entirely trivial, but you could create your own custom renderer to draw a scalable "circle x". Docs for extending bokeh are here: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html  If you do what to try that approach, the mailing list is probably better for collaborative, iterative discussion than SO: https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/?pli=1#!forum/bokeh

Comment: Thank you! I just realized one wierd behaviour: if I pass one-column DataFrames to `x` & `y` with fix `radius=10` then everything is plotted well. But if `radius` gets a one-column DataFrame (through `ColumnDataSource`) then nothing is plotted. If I pass `Series` object to `radius` (and/or `x`, `y`) then everything works perfectly.